# check session in this type of server

Tags: php, session

I am working on a type of server with the below information:

Apache/1.3.37 (Unix) PHP/5.2.3 mod_perl/1.30 DAV/1.0.3

I have previously asked how to view active sessions handled by the web server and was given the answer to do a php info page and view under "session.save_path" for the directory where they are stored. Unfortunately this specific server comes up with a "no value" for both of local and master value. Im pretty sure it has sessions though because my test files work with all the test cases I've used.

Thanks.

Comment: I should mention that the test cases/files work under a LAMP server of "Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-29-generic x86_64)" and I am able to check sessions from inside /var/lib/php5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this website http://blog.outsourcing-partners.com/2012/05/php-sessions-not-working-correctly-tips-and-tricks/

In particular, I used the .htaccess method and created one for the directory I was on. Specifically adding, "php_value session.save_path /tmp" so everything is now getting saved in the tmp folder.